# Under what circumstances, the status of the device will change to disabled or deleted

Tags: android-management-api

There are four state for deivce, I only find ACTIVE and PROVISIONING, how can device state will change to DISABLED or DELETED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISABLED** -  The device is disabled.

**DELETED** -   The device was deleted. This state will never be returned by an API call, but is used in the final status report published to Cloud Pub/Sub when the device acknowledges the deletion.

If you want to change the device `state` you need to modify the field by a patch request.
You can do this by calling `enterprises.devices.patch`

Note that when calling `enterprises.devices.patch`, `ACTIVE` and `DISABLED` are the only allowable values. To enter the device into a `DELETED` state, call `enterprises.devices.delete`

You can find more info on this page https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices

Comment: what does but is used in the final status report published to Cloud Pub/Sub when the device acknowledges the deletion mean?
I never recieve a delete status report from Cloud Pub/Sub when device deleted or factory reset